# Write to STDOUT Hangs

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

I've written a simple utility in .NET that reads from a serial port and writes the data to the console. However, I've noticed that after a short amount of time, calls to Console.Write hang indefinitely. I switched to P/Invoking WriteFile, but run into the same problem.

The code to display the data:

```
private static void DisplayData(byte[] data, int length)
{
    int written;
     IntPtr stdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    bool success = WriteFile(stdHandle, data, length, out written, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

At the time of the call that hangs, the data to be written is 
`"$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,M,,M,,*66\r\n$GPGNS,,,,,,N,,,,,,,U*7A\r\n$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C\r\n$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N,U*2A\r\n$GPGSA,M,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1*0F\r\n$GPGST,,,,,,,,*57\r\n"`.

I've checked to ensure that the buffer is sufficiently large (0x1000 bytes), compared to the length (0x9D bytes). I am unsure why the call to WriteFile hangs for such a simple write operation.

Comment: Have you tried to flush it at appropriate times? It probably fills the buffer and then flushes - which may take some time.

Comment: A call to Console.Out.Flush() fixes it. Thanks.